# How to access the Gmail RSS feed?

Tags: gmail, http, rss

I am trying to fetch the [Gmail Inbox RSS feed](https://developers.google.com/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed) using `curl`:

```bsh
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <my token>" https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom
```

The above command fails to fetch the feed and I get the following in my terminal.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have `read-only` access available to my token. Is it insufficient? I've also tried accessing the feed using simple `GET https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom` command and then providing my credentials through the terminal. That fails as well. Though I am able to load it properly in my web browser. What am I missing here?
Also, I'd like to state that I don't have a GSuite account.

Comment: _Note: This feed is only available for Gmail accounts on G Suite domains._

Comment: @SathyajithBhat I had the same thought, but if that were the case, why am I able to access it through my web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a token, you can try to use [*Basic Auth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) as this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/380652/87805):

```
wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1 --timeout=3 -t 1 -q -O- "https://user:password1@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"
```

Comment: Doesn't output anything when I run this.